# How do I write an output from bash script to the second line of the CSV file that contains headers?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have a bash script that writes its output to the beginning of a CSV file. I need it to maintain the headers on the first line. I tried to use awk and sed but didn't succeed.

I got the main script which is used to make a SSH connection:

```
for n in $(cat list.txt)
do
ssh -t root@$n /etc/m_chkdsk_app.sh
done
```

list.txt contains servers names

```
 server1
 server2
 server3
 server4
```

and the run the following script on the remote computers

```
if [ -f   /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv  ]
then
    printf "$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv && printf "," >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv && printf "$(date +%d-%m-%Y)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv && df -h | grep /dev/mapper/rootvg-var | awk '{printf "," $2 "," $3 "," $5 "," $6 "\n"}' >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv

    printf "$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv && printf "," >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv && printf "$(date +%d-%m-%Y)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv && df -h | grep "/dev/mapper/rootvg-sap " | awk '{printf "," $2 "," $3 "," $5 "," $6 "\n"}' >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv

    cat /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv       >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv
    mv /lnxfiler/diskstatus/New_m_chkdsk.csv   /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv

else

    printf "$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv && printf "," >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv && printf "$(date +%d-%m-%Y)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv && df -h | grep /dev/mapper/rootvg-var | awk '{printf "," $2 "," $3 "," $5 "," $6 "\n"}' >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv

    printf "$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv && printf "," >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv && printf "$(date +%d-%m-%Y)" >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv && df -h | grep "/dev/mapper/rootvg-sap " | awk '{printf "," $2 "," $3 "," $5 "," $6 "\n"}' >> /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv

fi

exit
```

When I run the main script, I need all the output of the script to be added after the header.

```
 Server Name,Date,Disk Size,Used,Use%,Mounted on
 server1,08-09-2020,2.0G,363M,20%,/var
 server1,08-09-2020,15G,41M,1%,/usr/sap
 server1,08-09-2020,200G,237M,1%,/suse_manager
 server2,08-09-2020,2.0G,138M,8%,/var
 server2,08-09-2020,20G,6.6G,36%,/srv
 server2,08-09-2020,80G,6.7G,9%,/srv/NFS
 server3,08-09-2020,2.0G,363M,20%,/var
 server3,08-09-2020,15G,41M,1%,/usr/sap
 server4,08-09-2020,2.0G,138M,8%,/var
 server4,08-09-2020,20G,6.6G,36%,/srv
 server4,08-09-2020,80G,6.7G,9%,/srv/NFS
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your efforts in form of code. Could you please do add sample of input and expected output for better understanding of question, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: `printf "$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)"` ? Just `cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname >>`. `How do I write an output from bash script to the second line of the CSV file that contains headers?` 1. Extract first line from file. 2. Write first line to file overwriting it and truncating it. 3. Continue with your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick refactoring.

Driver script; [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor):

```sh
head -n 1 result.csv >newresult.csv
while IFS= read -r host; do
do
    ssh -t "root@$host" /etc/m_chkdsk_app.sh </dev/null
done < list.txt >>newresult.csv
mv newresult.csv result.csv
```

Remote script:

```sh
df -h /dev/mapper/rootvg-var /dev/mapper/rootvg-sap | 
awk -v date=$(date +%d-%m-%Y) 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
  NR==FNR { host=$0; next }
  /\/dev/ { print host, date, $2, $3, $5, $6 }
  ' /proc/sys/kernel/hostname - |
tee /lnxfiler/diskstatus/m_chkdsk.csv
```

The original script had tremendous amounts of repetition but it's of course possible that I have overlooked some crucial difference between *almost* identical code snippets. That's actually one of the reasons to avoid repeating yourself.
Selectively overwriting the old results on the remote server in slightly different fashion depending on whether the file already exists seemed entirely superfluous, so I took that out.

This assumes that you have old results in `result.csv` and that the first header line is so incredibly hard to get right that you have to copy it from the old file.  It would probably be easier to just hard-code the script to write a new first line.

Depending on how robust you need this to be, maybe actually add `set -e` to the start of both scripts. If you don't absolutely have to store the results on the remote disk as well, that would cut out one of the main failure scenarios, and simpli|y the script still more.

Comment: You should put an `&&` between the `head` and the lop and again between the loop and the `mv` to avoid zapping `result.csv` on a failure, e.g. no permission to write to `newresult.csv`. Always write `foo file > tmp && mv tmp file` rather than `foo file > tmp; mv tmp file`.

Comment: Yeh, maybe then also add `set -e` to the remote script.

Comment: `date +"$HOSTNAME,%d-%m-%Y" | tr '\n' ,` to remove an extra `tr`?

Comment: @PaulHodges Mmmaybe that's too much of a micro-optimization? But thanks for the suggestion. Maybe a better design would be to pass everything to Awk and let it handle the formatting of the entire output line.

Comment: I went ahead and did just that. The old version is still in the edit history (but I haven't tested neither the old version nor this one).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `file1.csv` with data already in it, you can write all your new data to a `tempfile.csv` and then import it with an easy `sed` -

```
sed -i '1rtempfile.csv' file1.csv
```

This will read and add in the content of `tempfile` immediately after line 1.

Comment: I tried your solution for adding the temp file
     sed -i '2r m_chkdsk.csv' temp.csv
or
     sed -i '1r m_chkdsk.csv' temp.csv
none worked
also, can I add absolute path?
any advice?

Comment: If it isn't local you *must* use relative or absolute path.